# PHP CSV parsing - End of Line within a Field

Tags: php, csv

I am making my database process CSV files as an import of a legacy system.  One of the fields from the old system is 'comments.'  These comments my have a new line within that field.  How will PHP interpret a new line (I am not sure if it is `\n`, `\r`, or `\n\r`) within the `"` marks?  I have considered feeding the whole text file into a variable so I can replace the pieces of the string as I need, but it is a pretty big file.

Here is an simple example of the CVS file:

```
"ID Number","First Name","Last Name","Comments"\r\n
"1234","Jon","Doe","Jon and his family joined the organization 2010-01-01\r\n Jon married Jane 2011-02-14"\r\n
"2345","Mary","Smith",""
```

Notice that there are 2 lines in the comment field for Jon Doe.

Comment: show us the code you are using...

Comment: I have not started coding yet; I wanted feedback before starting.  Since the options `str_getcsv()` vs. `fgetcsv()` require different setup, I wanted to make a decision before starting.  I feel confident that I am capable of programming it either way; my question is really asking which would be BETTER for my situation.  I think `fgetcsv()` would be better in general, but I am wondering if the extra `\n`/`\r\n` in the CSV file will make that method not work.

Comment: I have an answer (and related parser function) at https://stackoverflow.com/q/25219967/209139.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking farther I found [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#107911).  Apparently `\n` within `"` is treated as part of the field, not a signal to start a new record.