# Parsing CSV in PHP and trying to keep line breaks in field contents

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file in which one of the columns there are line breaks.  The column is a description field so it stores lines of text, bulleted points, and most importantly line breaks--and sometimes two between paragraphs. To complicate matters, the description field also contains quotes.

I have tried everything I know to get the content (and keeping the formatting) into a variable.  I have tried file_get_contents, str_getcsv and fgetcsv to no avail. One of the functions let me put the entire description field into a variable, but it stripped all the new lines, so everything is in one giant paragraph.  Another one separately parsed each paragraph within the description field, instead of one single unit.

This is the general format of my csv file:

```
"391","The Great Gatsby","The Great Gatsby, F. Scott Fitzgerald’s third book, stands as the supreme achievement of his career. 

This exemplary novel of the Jazz Age has been acclaimed by generations of readers. The story of the fabulously wealthy Jay Gatsby and his love for the beautiful Daisy Buchanan, of lavish parties on Long Island at a time when The New York Times noted “gin was the national drink and sex the national obsession,” it is an exquisitely crafted tale of America in the 1920s.

The Great Gatsby is one of the great classics of twentieth-century literature.","No","Yes",
```

I'd like to have a variable where `$array[0]=391`, `$array[1]=The Great Gatsby` and most importantly `$array[2]` contains the text in the description with all the line breaks and formatting, including the quotes within the field itself.

Or if there's a better way to parse this using PHP, please let me know.

Comment: Did you try [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: No, I will check it out now

Comment: fgetcsv() should read this correctly; but line breaks won't show in a web browser, unless you wrap the text in <xmp> or <code> tags, or use nl2br() before displaying it

Comment: For now, I'm not trying to get it to show in a web browser. I'm trying to dump it into a database and keep the formatting the same.  fgetcsv is parsing each line of the description field separately instead of one single unit.

Comment: Actually, now I'm getting fgetcsv to parse the entire description field, but it is stripping all of the new lines/carriage returns. So, everything is one giant paragraph.

Comment: Everything ___looks___ like one giant paragraph in a browser, unless you use nl2br() when you display it

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use nl2br with either fgetcsv or file_get_contents+str_getcsv?

Comment: You use it when you display the data, not when you read it.... `echo nl2br($comments);` - see [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 3):

if someone still having this problem in 2019 my solution was `fgetcsv($file)`. Automatically respect the linebreaks inside text fields.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why this was _not_ working on my file (I knew it used to work...), until I figured out that it was encoded in UTF-16 (but of course PHP was reading it as a "normal" file, one byte at a time...). So beware the encoding!

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a function myself for precisely this use-case.

The PHP function `str_getcsv()` is for interpreting a single *line* of CSV data. Often, you can simply explode the file on new lines, and then parse each line individually, but what do you do when fields themselves may contain new lines?

The trick is to use `str_getcsv()` *twice*: once to split the file into lines, and again to split each individual line.

```
/**
 * Receives CSV string and returns as an array.
 *
 * *************************************************************************
 *
 * Based on code by fab at tradermail dot info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#119666
 */
function csv_to_array($csv, $delimiter=',', $header_line=true) {
    // CSV from external sources may have Unix or DOS line endings. str_getcsv()
    // requires that the "delimiter" be one character only, so we don't want
    // to pass the DOS line ending \r\n to that function. So first we ensure
    // that we have Unix line endings only.
    $csv = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $csv);

    // Read the CSV lines into a numerically indexed array. Use str_getcsv(),
    // rather than splitting on all linebreaks, as fields may themselves contain
    // linebreaks.
    $all_lines = str_getcsv($csv, "\n");
    if (!$all_lines) {
        return false;
    }

    $csv = array_map(
        function(&$line) use ($delimiter) {
            return str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);
        },
        $all_lines
    );

    if ($header_line) {
        // Use the first row's values as keys for all other rows.
        array_walk(
            $csv,
            function(&$a) use ($csv) {
                $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
            }
        );
        // Remove column header row.
        array_shift($csv);
    }

    return $csv;
}
```

Bonus: This function can also (if `$header_line`) return an associative array, using the first line as key names.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem while doing huge database uploads so I added a bit of code inside the loop.  It checks if the header field count matches the fields count at each pass, and if not it gets the next array from fgetcsv, and continues until they match the field count. So if you have 100 line breaks across any number of fields they will all be preserved.

```
$file = fopen($filenam,"r");

$count=0;

while (($fields = fgetcsv($file,0,"|")) !== false) 
   
 {
    
            $count++;
            if($count == 1)  {
                $sql_fields=[];$fc=0;
                foreach($fields as $field) {
                    //$sql_fields .= $field.",";
                    $sql_fields[] = $field;
                    $fc++;
                }
                continue;
            }
            
            if(count($fields)!=$fc) {
                if($gotprev!='') {
                    $gotprev .= implode("|",$fields);
                    $fields = explode("|",$gotprev);
                    if(count($fields)!=$fc)
                        continue;
                    $gotprev='';
                }else{
                     $gotprev = implode("|",$fields);
                     continue;
                }    
                
            }
            
            $sql_values='';$rc=0;$sql_fields_gen='';
            foreach($sql_fields as $key=>$field) {
                   
                if($fields[$key]=='False') $fields[$key]=0;
                if($fields[$key]=='True') $fields[$key]=1;
                $sql_values .= "'".addslashes($fields[$key])."',";
                $rc++;
                $sql_fields_gen .= $field.",";
            }
                
            
            $sql_fields_gen = "(".rtrim($sql_fields_gen,",").")";
            $sql_values = "VALUES (".rtrim($sql_values,",").")";
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO mytable $sql_fields_gen $sql_values ";                
            $DB->execute($sql_insert);           
}
```