# Why is str_getcsv() stripping quotation marks within fields?

Tags: php, csv

The `str_getcsv()` function is designed to work on a *line* of CSV text, not on a set of lines. I am trying to use it twice, once to split multiple lines of CSV into an array of lines, and then again on each of those. This solution was working for me, and indeed [I supplied it as an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579128/209139).

However, I now have a problem whereby the line `"AC150AC,",service tool,845.71,-2` is returned as `AC150AC,,service tool,845.71,-2`, with the quotation marks removed, so the comma is now treated as a separator. In debugging that, I found that multi-line values are now also not working, and are now split in the middle despite being enclosed correctly.

How can I debug this?

```
$ cat csv.php 
<?php

$csv = '130,TEST A 1258 (U10 001),28.66,2
"AC150AC,",service tool,845.71,-2
AL7951,SEA LION,47.19,2
T11,"Test multi-
line segments",587.36,4';

$n = str_getcsv($csv, "\n");
$r = str_getcsv($csv, "\r");

print_r($n);
print_r($r);

$ xxd csv.php 
00000000: 3c3f 7068 700a 0a24 6373 7620 3d20 2731  <?php..$csv = '1
00000010: 3330 2c54 4553 5420 4120 3132 3538 2028  30,TEST A 1258 (
00000020: 5531 3020 3030 3129 2c32 382e 3636 2c32  U10 001),28.66,2
00000030: 0a22 4143 3135 3041 432c 222c 7365 7276  ."AC150AC,",serv
00000040: 6963 6520 746f 6f6c 2c38 3435 2e37 312c  ice tool,845.71,
00000050: 2d32 0a41 4c37 3935 312c 5345 4120 4c49  -2.AL7951,SEA LI
00000060: 4f4e 2c34 372e 3139 2c32 0a54 3131 2c22  ON,47.19,2.T11,"
00000070: 5465 7374 206d 756c 7469 2d0a 6c69 6e65  Test multi-.line
00000080: 2073 6567 6d65 6e74 7322 2c35 3837 2e33   segments",587.3
00000090: 362c 3427 3b0a 0a24 6e20 3d20 7374 725f  6,4';..$n = str_
000000a0: 6765 7463 7376 2824 6373 762c 2022 5c6e  getcsv($csv, "\n
000000b0: 2229 3b0a 2472 203d 2073 7472 5f67 6574  ");.$r = str_get
000000c0: 6373 7628 2463 7376 2c20 225c 7222 293b  csv($csv, "\r");
000000d0: 0a0a 7072 696e 745f 7228 246e 293b 0a70  ..print_r($n);.p
000000e0: 7269 6e74 5f72 2824 7229 3b0a 0a         rint_r($r);..

$ php csv.php 
Array
(
    [0] => 130,TEST A 1258 (U10 001),28.66,2
    [1] => AC150AC,,service tool,845.71,-2
    [2] => AL7951,SEA LION,47.19,2
    [3] => T11,"Test multi-
    [4] => line segments",587.36,4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 130,TEST A 1258 (U10 001),28.66,2
"AC150AC,",service tool,845.71,-2
AL7951,SEA LION,47.19,2
T11,"Test multi-
line segments",587.36,4
)
```

Comment: Bonus question: How can I convince vendors to export data in JSON or XML instead of CSV, a [multi-dialectal kludge](https://frictionlessdata.io/specs/csv-dialect/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are splitting it by end of line characters(of various types) which you don't know if they are mid line or genuine end of lines.

A fudge is to use `fgetcsv()` to do the work for you, so you first have to give it a file to work with.  This code creates a temporary file, writes the contents to it and then rewinds the file so the read starts from the beginning...

```
$fh = tmpfile();
fwrite($fh, $csv);
fseek($fh, 0);

while ( $row = fgetcsv($fh))   {
    print_r($row);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: I'll play with it further, but [is that even valid](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50686)?

Comment: It seems to be working, but I don't think your use of `fseek()` is necessary (or valid, as `SEEK_SET` should be the third parameter).

Comment: You are correct about the placement of the SEEK_SET, although as it's defined as being 0, this just happened to work as I was expecting.  As for not using it at all, it's essential otherwise the file pointer is left at the end of the file after the `fwrite()`.  Try commenting it out and you get no output.